# What is the meaning of current at infinite time for a series RLC circuit formula

Tags: voltage, current, passive-networks, theory

I am reading [this doc](http://www.d.umn.edu/~snorr/ece2006s4/Lab8a.PDF).

At one point, the author says the current equation form a critically damped series RLC circuit when a step function is applied is:

\$ I_L(t) = I_{\infty} + (B_1 + B_2t)e^{-\alpha t} \$

As far as I know, on a critically damped RLC circuit current will oscillate and  be like this

[image]

\$ I_{\infty} \$ will be an equation, not a value, right?

What is the the meaning of this \$ I_{\infty} \$ on the current equation and how do I find it?

Comment: The ringing is decreasing with time. A step function has only one change, at t=0, after than it is constant. The current will approach a single value over time.

Comment: thanks and how do I find it from the equations?

Comment: If you have the solution to the differential equation, then it's simple, allow t to go to infinity and the exponential term goes to zero. If you don't have the solution, well you know that a capacitor acts as an open circuit after a long time, and an inductor acts as a short.

Comment: so, for a circuit where the capacitor/inductor are both initially discharged current at infinity will stabilize to zero, given the capacitor will be an open circuit, right? Please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept. THANKS

Comment: Critically damped is \$\zeta = 1 \$, or no ringing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the solution to the differential equation, then it's simple, allow t to go to infinity and the exponential term goes to zero.

The function you show is *underdamped* (complex roots), overdamped will have real roots and critically damped has repeated real roots.

If you don't have the solution, well you know that a capacitor acts as an open circuit after a long time, and an inductor acts as a short.

So a parallel RLC circuit will have zero voltage after a long time, and a series RLC circuit will have zero current. Regardless of the (presumed finite) initial conditions.